# Get the image of Web Page

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ios5, ios4

I'm trying to capture the full image of the web page.. 
But its showing the blank image..

what should i do to get the complete Web Page Image?

I have tried with

```
CGSize overallSize = [WebPageImage sizeThatFits:CGSizeZero];
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(WebPageImage.scrollView.contentSize);
WebPageImage.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, overallSize.width, overallSize.height);
while (WebPageImage.loading) {
    [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:0.1];
}
UIImage *viewImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT,(unsigned long)NULL), ^(void) {
    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(viewImage, self, @selector(image:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:), nil);
});
```

Please suggest some solution..
WebPageImage is UIWebView..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(WebPageImage.bounds.size, WebPageImage.opaque, 0.0);
[WebPageImage.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Comment: This answer is complete and perfect +1.

Comment: its giving error at "[printWebPage.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];" and error is "ViewController.m:66:6: Receiver type 'CALayer' for instance message is a forward declaration"..

Comment: not sure, you may need to add QuartzCore.framework &&  #import  <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

Comment: thanks for your answer but its not giving the whole image.. its showing only the wed page part which is displayed on screen..

Comment: yeah,  but it's the only method to capture the webview's image,  you can figure it out you self by adjust the size of the drawing , &  maybe draw several times to draw the whole page  :)   i only can provide a way to reach that

Comment: you can get the webview's contentSize  &  move the webview's contentOffset   , so you can calculate youself & draw the entire page

Comment: but every time i get the web page its size and offset will change with different URL ya..

Comment: or you can try to resize the webview  to the contentSize ,  then  draw it

Comment: i mean ， you can resize it & draw it , then  resize back to the original size

Answer (score 1):

use this function according to your need. below code will give you snapshot of whole webpage

```
- (UIImage *) imageFromWebView:(UIWebView *)view
{
//    tempframe to reset view size after image was created
    CGRect tmpFrame     = view.frame;

    // set new Frame
    CGRect aFrame       = view.frame;
    aFrame.size.height  = [view sizeThatFits:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size].height;
    aFrame.size.width   = [view sizeThatFits:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size].width;
    view.frame          = aFrame;

//     do image magic
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext([view sizeThatFits:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size]);
    CGContextRef resizedContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    [self.thmbWebView.layer renderInContext:resizedContext];
    UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    // reset Frame of view to origin
    view.frame = tmpFrame;
    return image;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
[WebPageImage.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
```

Answer (score 0):

try to capture that image with my bellow method...

```
-(IBAction)captureScreen:(id)sender
{   
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(webview.frame.size);
    [webview.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    UIImage *viewImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(viewImage, nil, nil, nil);
}
```

Also see my another answer from this link.. [howe-to-capture-uiview-top-uiview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14049796/howe-to-capture-uiview-top-uiview/14049828#14049862)

Comment: here you get which you want dude... here its working with whole view.. here instead of WebPageImage you can set self.view ..

Comment: here set need to set opaque to the UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions method.. and it will worked like adali says...

Comment: its not working here dude.. i tried with other options also.. all are giving the part of web page which is visible..

Comment: @Raju here you set option with its above method which have this syntax  UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(<#CGSize size#>, <#BOOL opaque#>, <#CGFloat scale#>) , so here opaqe pass differ and it will worked... if you used self.view then it worked but here for webview use option...

Comment: oh you want to get inner page of UIWebView's screenshot??

Comment: @Raju see now i capture two images and its give me the screenshot of webPage only.. try to change the frame of UIWebView its give you image of that uiwebview's frame size.. try now... :)

Comment: still its giving the same half web page image..:( is it possible to get 2 or 3 images, so that we can get entire page?

Comment: see this link.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5763986/iphone-auto-resizing-uiwebview-content-do-not-fit-the-frame hope this help ypu.. :)

Comment: No still i'm getting the same partial image of UIWebView..:(