# UIWebView does not fit to device screen

Tags: ios, swift, uiwebview

I have a web view that I want to fill the full screen of a iDevice. I placed it in the center of the view set to be center and flush with the edge of the container. However when I load the app, the view is larger than the emulated iPhone it is running in. I have done some searching and some suggest auto layout, which is already supposed to be centering the view. Another thing I found was to set the size though code.

```
self.webView.frame = self.view.bounds
```

I even changed the app from a universal app to just iPhone, with no effect on the layout.

Full source:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var webView: UIWebView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        self.webView.frame = self.view.bounds

        webView.frame = self.view.bounds
        var uri = NSURL(string:"http://google.com")
        var req = NSURLRequest(URL: uri)
        webView.loadRequest(req)
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}
```

Comment: set **scalesPageToFit=yes**

Comment: need more ref try this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5763986/iphone-auto-resizing-uiwebview-content-do-not-fit-the-frame)

Comment: My issue is not that the content will not fill the web view. It's that the web view will not fill the screen of the device

Comment: Have a look on this answer - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26133144/uiscrollview-and-constraints/26135270#26135270

Comment: That was it! Can you add this to your answer so I can select it?

Answer (score 10):

Set the scaling to fit the view bounds. Try this:

```
self.webView.frame = self.view.bounds
self.webView.scalesPageToFit = true
```

Hope this helps.. :)

Comment: Thanks, I gave it a shot but I get the same results. Maybe I'm missing something fundamental about the layout of the view. Do I have to set it for every combination of layout in the story board?

Comment: @QueueHammer > Can you post your storyboard settings? and the constraints you set on webview?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to set this programetically then
One way to do this is add this 4 constraint to your webView this way:

[image]

This works for me.

Comment: The left and the right constraints works but it won't let me set the constraints for the top and the bottom.